# QueryOver<A>().Where(a => a.B.Count() > 0) does not work

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I get an exception: `Unrecognised method call in epression a.B.Count()` when I run:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<A>()
    .Where(a => a.B.Count() > 0)
    .List();
```

The following code works:

```
var query1 = session.QueryOver<A>().List();
var query2 = query1.Where(a => a.B.Count() > 0);
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

---

**Edit:**

Here is my mappings. I'm using NHibernate 3.1.0.4000:

Models:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
public class AMappings : ClassMap<A>
{
    public AMappings()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.Bs).LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class BMappings : ClassMap<B>
{
    public BMappings()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

Rest of my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create connection string
        string connectionString = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
                                   {
                                      DataSource = @".\r2",
                                      InitialCatalog = "TestNHibernateMappings",
                                      IntegratedSecurity = true
                                   }.ConnectionString;

        // Create SessionFactory
        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration
                      .MsSql2008.ConnectionString(connectionString)
                      .ShowSql())
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
            .Add(typeof(AMappings))
            .Add(typeof(BMappings)))
        .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
        .BuildConfiguration()
        .BuildSessionFactory();

        // Test
        var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

        // This line works OK
        var query1 = session.Query<A>()
            .Where(a => a.Bs.Count() > 0);

        // This line throws exception: Unrecognised method call in epression a.Bs.Count()
        var query2 = session.QueryOver<A>()
            .Where(a => a.Bs.Count() > 0);
    }

    static void BuildSchema(Configuration cfg)
    {
        new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume it's a typo in the second example and `query.Where` should be `query1.Where`?

Comment: @pickypg: Thanks, typo corrected.

Comment: Can you show your mappings? And what version of NHibernate do you use?

Comment: @bniwredyc: I'm trying to replicate this issue in another project, then post the mappings. I'm using NHibernate 5.1.0.4000.

Comment: @caveman: you meant 3.1.0.4000? Please add code of the A class and its mapping to your question.

Comment: @bniwredyc: Yes, I meant 3.1.0.4000. I've updated my question with my models and mappings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QueryOver is not LINQ.

Your second code snippet works because it's retrieving ALL THE RECORDS and using LINQ-to-objects in memory.

What you should do is:

```
session.Query<A>()
       .Where(a => a.B.Count() > 0)
       .ToList();
```

or better yet:

```
session.Query<A>()
       .Where(a => a.B.Any())
       .ToList();
```

`Query` is an extension method, you need to add `using NHibernate.Linq;`

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! One more question: Do you mean this feature is not supported in QueryOver? I mean is it possible to translate this code into QueryOver statement?